# Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6 and connecting to dynamodb to fetch data.
Getting above error on line `json.dumps(item, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder)`
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

```
import json
import boto3
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('MY_TABLE')

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    category_id = event["queryStringParameters"]["id"]
    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'category': category_id
            }
           )    

    item = response['Item']
    return {
     "isBase64Encoded": False,
     "statusCode": '200',
     "headers": {},
     "body": json.dumps(item, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder)
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON does not support sets so you should make your customer decoder for `json.dumps` able to convert sets to lists:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, set):
            return list(o)
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, I modified my customer decoder and it decoded set.